# During notice period unable to perform my duties due to lack of skills, but willingness to serve notice period

Tags: india, notice-period

I am from India. I have resigned from my current organization and the reason I have resigned because I lack the skills to perform the tasks expected to be performed. Now, even after resigning the management wants me to perform the tasks. What can happen if I am physically / virtually present but unable to perform my duties? While I ensure I am available for 8 hours a day? Notice period is 75 days and its just a week I have resigned. Kindly advice.

Comment: You can't learn the skills in 75 days? How did you get the job?

Answer (score 8):

If your employer is requesting it, turn up to work (whether that be virtually or physically) and do the best you can. That's all anyone can ask of you.

Yes, it's stupid that they'll pay you to sit there and be unproductive, but that's their choice.

Comment: I'm sure there are buildings full of employees who don't have the skills to do their job.